# show that $\sum_{i = 1}^{2k}\frac{ (-1)^{i+1}}{i} = \sum_{i = k+1}^{2k} \frac{1}{i}$

Tags: summation

I have a proof but it does not seem elegant. Is there a more elegant solution? Thanks.

Consider $X = \sum_{i = 1}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i} = X_1 + X_2$ where

$X_1 = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}$

$X_2 = \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2} + ... + \frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{2k}$

$k$ is even.

Every negative term $d$ in $X_2$ is of the form $\frac{1}{2^my}$ where $y$ is odd and could be $1$. Also $y \le k$

For every such $d$, we will have the following terms 
$\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{2y} - ... - \frac{1}{2^{m-1}y}$ in $X_1$. 
Adding $d$ to the above, we get

$\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{2y} - ... - \frac{1}{2^{m-1}y} - \frac{1}{2^my} = \frac{1}{2^my}$

So every negative term $d$ in $X_2$ is now replaced with a term of the same magnitude but with a positive sign.

Hence $X = \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k+2} + ... + \frac{1}{2k-1} + \frac{1}{2k}$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{i = 1}^{2k}{\pars{-1}^{i + 1} \over i} =
> \sum_{i = k + 1}^{2k}{1 \over i}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{2k}{\pars{-1}^{i + 1} \over i} & =
\sum_{i = 1}^{k}{1 \over 2i - 1} - \sum_{i = 1}^{k}{1 \over 2i} =
\pars{\sum_{i = 1}^{2k}{1 \over i} - \sum_{i = 1}^{k}{1 \over 2i}} -
\sum_{i = 1}^{k}{1 \over 2i}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{i = 1}^{2k}{1 \over i} - \sum_{i = 1}^{k}{1 \over i} =
\bbx{\ds{\sum_{i = k + 1}^{2k}{1 \over i}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: @sku Thanks. Separation of $even$ and $odd$ always seems to work !!!.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_k=\sum_{k=1}^{2k}(-1)^{i+1}/i$ and $T_k=\sum_{i+1}^{2i}1/i$. Then
$$T_k-T_{k-1}=\frac1{2k-1}+\frac1{2k}-\frac1k=\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}=
S_k-S_{k-1}.$$
Obviously, $S_0=T_0$ so by induction....

Comment: Elegant solution!!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there's a much simpler way:

$$S=\sum^{2k}_{i=1}\left[\frac{(-1)^{(i+1)}}{i}\right]=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6} \cdot\cdot\cdot +\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}$$

$$S=\color{blue}{\left[\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6} \cdot\cdot\cdot +\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\right]}-2\color{red}{\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdot\cdot\cdot\frac{1}{2k}\right]}$$
$$S=\sum^{2k}_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}-2\sum^k_{i=1}\frac{1}{2i}=\sum^{2k}_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}-\sum^k_{i=1}\frac{2}{2i}=\color{purple}{\sum^{2k}_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}-\sum^k_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}}=\sum^{2k}_{i=k+1}\frac{1}{i}$$

Hence proved.

---

Note: $$\sum^{2k}_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}=\sum^{k}_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}+\sum^{2k}_{i=k+1}\frac{1}{i}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use *[harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)* 
$H_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{i}$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k}\frac{1}{i}=\color{blue}{H_{2k}-H_k}
> \end{align*}
>
> on the other hand we get
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}-H_{2k}
> &=-2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2k}\right)=-H_k\\
> \end{align*}
>
> which implies
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}
> &=\color{blue}{H_{2k}-H_k}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.